# Transient transition that sets a value only on condition passing

Tags: state, state-management, xstate

Take the following code:

```js
const isWarning = () => { ... }
const setWarning = () => { ... }

const machine = Machine({
  initial: "foo",
  context: {
    warning: null
  },
  states: {
    foo: {
      on: {
        "": [
          target: "bar",
          action: "setWarning",
          cond: "isWarning",
        ]
      }
    },
    bar: {
      on: {
        FOO: "foo,
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  actions: {
    setWarning
  }
  guards: {
    isWarning
  }
});
```

Is this the best way to go to "bar" **and** set a warning based on some quantitative data in "foo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the posted code example, I am not sure what you mean by **"quantitative data in foo"**. Data relevant for machine's behavior can be stored in machine's `context` or state's `meta` property. 
For getting into `bar` state **and** set a warning you might need something like:

```
    const sm = Machine({
      initial: 'baz',
      context: { wasWarned: false },
      on: {
        'WARNING': {
            target: 'bar',
            action: 'setWarning'     
        }
      },
      states: {
        baz: {},
        bar: {}
      }  
    }, {
      actions: {
        setWarning: assign({ warning: true })
      }
    })
```

This means: When machine gets 'WARNING' event, go into `bar` state AND immediately, [before anything else](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/actions.html#declarative-actions) update the context.

> Actions are not immediately triggered. Instead, the State object returned from machine.transition(...) will declaratively provide an array of `.actions` that an interpreter can then execute.

The [transition will be enabled](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/transitions.html#selecting-enabled-transitions) **after** the guards are passed.

Other code example that might prove useful depending on what you want to achieve:

```
const sm = Machine({
      initial: 'pending',
      context: { wasWarned: null },
      states: {
        pending: {
          on: {
            '': [
             {target: 'bar', cond:'wasWarned'},
             {target: 'baz', cond: 'otherCond'} 
            ]
          }
        },
        bar: {},
        baz: {}
      },
      guards: {
        wasWarned: (ctx) => ctx.wasWarned
      }
    })
```